# argparser.ArgumentParser change between python 2.7 and python 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I have next line in python

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(version = version, description = desc, epilog= "{}\n\n{}".format(example,credit), formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)

**When I run with python 2.7, there is no problem.
But when I run with python 3.6 , I got this error:**

File "MY_FILE.py", line 97, in 
main()

File "MY_FILE.py", line 60, in main
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(version = version,description = desc, epilog= "{}\n\n{}".format(example,credit), formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'version'

Is there some update fix I need to do in order to run with python 3.6 ?

Comment: Early versions of argparse had a `version` argument analogous to `help`.  That's been gone for quite some time.  READ THE DOCS.  Omit that parameter.

Comment: ok, ommit the parameter solved the problem, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

the version argument is no longer supported in python 3.6, it can be included as a part of "help" now. The Documentation for Python 2 and Python 3 clears it up. The program should work when you remove this parameter.